# VBA Extract Parent Folder Name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the name (not path) of the parent folder of the active workbook.

The full path is:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Testing\Projects\002-Latest\Products\Product001.xlsm

The following code gets me the current folder (Products) but I want to go 1 more level up (002-Latest)

```
ProjectFolder = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\") + 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `Split` function instead of the way you are doing it.

```
Sub test()
  MsgBox GetParentFolder("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Testing\Projects\002-Latest\Products\Product001.xlsm")
End Sub


Function GetParentFolder(sFullname As String) As String
  Dim vSplit As Variant
  
  vSplit = Split(sFullname, "\")
  GetParentFolder = vSplit(UBound(vSplit) - 1)
End Function
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks braX